# ngFor call custom function for each iteration

Tags: angular

I want to implement something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let callLog of callLogs; trackBy: trackByFn; let contact = getContact(callLog.user-id);" class="call-log-item">
     ...
     <div> {{ contact ? contact.name : callLog.cache-name }}
     <div> {{ contact ? contact.avatar-url : callLog.avatar-url }}
     ... 
</div>
```

But calling the above getContact(callLog) in ngFor loop cause template parse error.

Is it possible to call custom function for each ng loop iteration? Or any good suggestion to achieve what i want.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another template inside the `NgForOf`, for example you could use an `NgIf` :

```
<div *ngFor="let callLog of callLogs; trackBy: trackByFn" class="call-log-item">
    <ng-container *ngIf="getContact(callLog.user-id) as contact"
     ...
     <div> {{ contact ? contact.name : callLog.cache-name }}
     <div> {{ contact ? contact.avatar-url : callLog.avatar-url }}
     ... 
    <ng-container>
</div>
```

Using functions inside the templates isn't a good practice, the function would be called a couple of times in each change detection cycle.

Answer (score 0):

it's better use forkJoin in code to create an array

forkJoin is easy, just must have an array of "calls",e.g.

```
import { forkJoin, } from 'rxjs';

//Create an array of Observables, I use map
let myCalls=callLogs.map(x=>this.getContact(x.user-id))
forkJoin(myCall).subscribe(res=>{
    //here you have an array with the result of all your calls
    this.list=res;
    console.log(this.list);
});
```

A silly example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6gvek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)