# How to call service with in for each?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, service

```
private Payload(): asset { 
    const payload = { //pay load }
    return payload; 
}
  
public listofnumbers() { 
    number = [1,2,3]; 
    number.forEach(element => { 
        this.service(element); 
    }); 
}
 
private service(number) {
    this.service.getNumbers(this.Payload())
        .subscribe((res) => { 
            if (res.isSuccess && res.data) { 
                this.function(); 
            } 
        }) 
} 

function () { alert("fghj"); }
```

When service is called instead of executing the HTTP call first it calls the method in inside service.
Not sure what to do?

using forkjoin

```
 public sendSelectedToD365() {
    let assetDetails1 = [];
      let assetSearchValue =(this.searchAssetForm.controls['assetSearch'].value).split(',');
      let mycalls = assetSearchValue.map(x => this.trying(x))
      forkJoin(mycalls).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)

      })
    }

  private trying(x)
      {     this.assetService.getAssetDetails(this.AssetDetailsPayload(x)).subscribe((res) => {
            if (res.isSuccess && res.data) {
              return res.data;
            }
        })
    }
```

What's wrong with this? I'm using forkjoin its not working as expected

Comment: what method is called inside service first, and I don't see an HTTP call in there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Angular service inside forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099964/call-angular-service-inside-foreach-loop)

Comment: i tried to make it a promise, but it's not working as excepted.

Comment: no, it doesn't help @R.Richards

Comment: Can any 1 tell me how to write the code with an example, I'm very new to angular .

Comment: @Sanjanak, use  forkJoin. You has an array of listofnumbers, using map you convert in an array of Observables, subcribing to forkJoin the array of observables you get in an array the response. There're a lot of examples of forkJoin in SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192839/ngfor-call-custom-function-for-each-iteration/53198125#53198125

Comment: Can u see the code above and tell me where I am going wrong @Eliseo

Comment: @Sanjanak, the forkjoin "join" observables, so your function trying sould return Observable. You subscribe in the forkjoin, **not** in trying. I wrote an answer to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sanjana, the "key" of forkjoin is "join" observables, so "trying" should return an observable

```
  public sendSelectedToD365() {
      let assetDetails1 = [];
      let assetSearchValue =(this.searchAssetForm.controls['assetSearch'].value).split(',');
      let mycalls = assetSearchValue.map(x => this.trying(x))
      forkJoin(mycalls).subscribe(res:any[] => {
        console.log(res)
        // in res[0] you has the response to the first call
        // in res[1] you has the response to the second one
        // ...
        res.forEach((x,index)=>{
          console.log("The response to",assetSearchValue[index],"is ",res[index])
        })

      })
    }

  private trying(x):Observable<any>
  {         
       //see that you use return the Observable
         return this.assetService.getAssetDetails(this.AssetDetailsPayload(x))
  }
```